# How do you implement user Goal Tracking in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, goal-tracking

How do you implement goal tracking. Any specific Way of doing. I am thinking storing of user goal in  Sqlite db  and accessing them and do the logic to track how much is reached. Is there are better way? So we can display the goals reached as completed or how much is completed on the screen , when user comes to screen, he sees how much the user has completed.

Comment: Users set goals, you track them based on their performance. Here you save the goal values in the sqlite and measure the performance. So when user comes to the screen , there is a display on how much user achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use SQLite to store user goals. I also recommend using an ORM library for easy management and save some time on setup the database. Try using [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) or [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) as two of the best.

Comment: Thnks Estevex, I looking at confirmation on Sqlite.  My fear was I was missing out on some important technique